# PHP and HTML PDF viewer

Tags: php, html

i am first time display the pdf in the html page
for this i am using HTML5 inbuilt code to display the PDF.
here below i mentioned the my code

```
<object data="http://localhost/app/akara/upload/1401213232.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="35%" height="500">
</object>
```

OR

```
<embed src="http://localhost/app/akara/upload/1401213232.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

both of the above working fine. I have also installed the IDM. so when ever i come on the page it ask me to download the PDF file. i want to remove this IDM to asking me this.
i dont want to change any IDM setting. i want to make it disable from my code.

can anyone tell me its solution.

Thansk in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can render PDF to canvas object using [this](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/rendering-pdf-in-html5-canvas/). Moreover, you can use any document viewer there are plent of them for example [this one](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/)